# How to leverage new Dynamic Icons from SLDS

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, slds

Interested in trying to use the new Dynamic Icons (https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/dynamic-icons/) from SLDS in a Lightning Component but can't quite figure out how...

Do I need to use the old deprecated method of creating a component for svgs:
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/lightning-svg-icon-component-helper/

or can these be used with the Lightning:Icon base component?

Comment: As far as I can see from documentation, the lightning:icon can support only specific set of icons by category specified here : https://lightningdesignsystem.com/icons/ All the references I looked for and sample codes still use the old method of SVG. Until there is a separate category added for dynamic icons you may have to use the SVG deprecated route is my thought. BTW My reference :  github implementing dynamic icons: https://github.com/jmdohn/dynamicIcons

Comment: Now that winter 18 is released for all orgs, you can use the standard lightning:dynamicIcon component.  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_dynamicIcon.htm